# Questions about Android ListViews and ArrayAdapters

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

So I'm toying with this code here, and the main objective is to update a list with a new item once I click a button. The code I have works, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it.

I have two methods. The first method takes my ArrayList, add's two strings and posts it to the listview. Great!

The Second method I have is called when I tap on a button. It add's a new string and updates the list, but in order for me to update the existing listview, I had to do the "setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter...." line again and I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do.

I can use some input please, thanks!

Method 1:

```
static final List list = new ArrayList();
private void showEvents (Cursor cursor){
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");
        Log.d(TAG,"showevent");
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem, list));



    }
```

Method 2 (this is called when I tap a button that is under the listView):

```
private void updateListView(){
        try{
            list.add("son");
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem, list));


        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "E="+e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than setting the list adapter again, call the notifyDataSetChanged() on the ArrayAdapter.  The above will "work", but it forces the entire ListView to redraw, so if you have a long list and the user has scrolled it'll pop them back to the top.  The notify is a cleaner way to do that.

Very simple code.  I've got a reference to the array adapter in the activity in this case:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Here's and example based on your code:

```
static final List list = new ArrayList();
ArrayAdapter adapter;

private void showEvents (Cursor cursor){
    list.add("foo");
    list.add("bar");
    Log.d(TAG,"showevent");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem, list)
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private void updateListView(){
    try{
        list.add("son");
        adapter.nofityDataSetChanged();
        // not needed anymore
        //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.singleitem, list));
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "E="+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to set that up. I moved the arraydapter on the outside of the method and did setListAdapter(adapter). I don't know how to go about this, could you help me re-write this so I can better understand this?

Answer (score 0):

declare a member variable for the `ArrayAdapter` (say `myAdapter`) and then initialise it in the `showEvents` method and set it to the listView. next in the `updateListView` method after adding string to your list just call `myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and that should do the trick